# About install Homestead per Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I'm using Homestead for Laravel Development Environment.

I installed globally Homestead, everything is ok.

However, when want install Homestead per Laravel project, I have a question:

Will I have to install PHP, Composer in Local machine to can run this command ?

```
composer require laravel/homestead --dev
```

So I still have to install environment (PHP, Composer, ...) on Local machine when want install Homestead per Laravel project ?

Comment: are you asking how do you go about installing homestead per project? I am sure you would know by now homestead is just a virtual box right?

Answer (score 1):

You ssh into your homestead box by cd'ing into your project folder and after successfully running `vagrant up` you run `vagrant ssh` and inside your box you can run all your commands.